# How to use JSF extension library as OSGI bundle

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, osgi, pom.xml

I want to use Primefaces library as osgi bundle in JSF application. I created WAB package with JSF pages. I also deployed promefaces.jar as OSGI bundle. I saw into the primefaces.jar that the MANIFEST file is exporting the packages to be visible for other bundles. The question is how I can use the primefaces tags into the the WAB bundle? I'm sure that I need to add configuration into the POM.xml file but I'm not sure how to do it.

I successfully tested to include primefaces.jar into the WAB by putting the .jar file into WEB-INF/lib directory but I want to use Primefaces as OSGI resource not as jar resource into the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy and paste the tags declaration in `primefaces-p.taglib.xml` file and also take a look at this [tutorial](http://simonmartinelli.blogspot.com/2009/09/create-custom-jsf-facelet-component.html) how to create custom tag.

Answer (score 4):

Is the WAB bundle an OSGi bundle too? 
If it is, you should simply import the packages you need in the manifest file of the WAB bundle. 
Include the packages by listing them under the Import-Package: entry.
This should make them visible to the whole WAB bundle.